# Почему в слове "растерянный" две буквы "н"?

Tags: орфография

Почему в слове "растерянный" две буквы "н"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

*"Растерянный"* может быть и полным отглагольным прилагательным, и причастием.

- В прилагательном *"растерянный"* пишутся две Н, так как оно образовано от глагола *"растеряться"*, который имеет приставку.
- В причастии *"растерянный"* пишутся две Н, потому что это -- страдательное причастие прошедшего времени, имеющее приставку.

Answer (score 2):

Налицо **адъективация** - ***переход страдательного причастия (в данном случае) в прилагательное***. В страдательном причастии с приставкой пишется НН, при переходе причастия в прилагательное сохраняются суффиксы -Я- и -НН-.